# multiple axis in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-axes, long-format-data

So I have a dataset for which I'm planning to create several graph through a loop using the unique ID of each set, here you'll able to see the how the graph looks for an single individual.

```
library(ggplot2)
RID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
COMP <- c(0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1)
TIME <- c(0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.06, 0,07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.11, 0.11, 0.15, 0.16, 0.19)
NDV <- c(23, 34, 54, 11, 23, 76, 45, 38, 22, 45, 98, 19, 10, 11, 56)

df <- data.frame(RID, COMP, TIME, NDV)
```

I created a function to graph the time course of all this datapoints (I've done this because the I'm planning to create multiple graphs and put that into a loop) with 2 axis atm.

```
graph_fx_ex <- function(df) {
  mycolors <- c("C1" = "blue", "C0" = "red", "C2" = "green", "C3" = "yellow", "Time (h)" = "black")
  ggplot(df, aes(x = TIME, y = NDV, group = as.factor(COMP), color = as.factor(COMP))) + 
    labs(title = paste("RID = ", df$RID[1])) +
    geom_path() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "comp 1 value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 1*., name = "comp 2 value")) +
    scale_x_continuous(name =  "Time (h)") +
    scale_color_manual(name = "case", values = c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow")) + 
    theme(
      axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(color = mycolors["C1"]),
      axis.text.y = element_text(color = mycolors["C1"]),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = mycolors["C0"]),
      axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = mycolors["C0"])
    )
}
```

when I resolve this for my dataset there's only 2 Y axis. however since I have 4 unique components I'd like to know how can I add more. I've read all the GGPLOT2 regarding multiple axis and nowhere have I found where to add parallel multiple Y axis.

```
graph_fx_ex(df)
```

[image]

I've used a long format for the class column (COMP) since the points don't share the actual times. How can I add more parallel axis to the graph to also include the other 2 classes?

Thanks :)

**IMPORTANT PIECE OF INFORMATION**:
COMP isn't multiple measurements of the same thing per ID, but distinct measurements (meaning just a single scale isn't possible). While COMP = 0 might codify for something like body temperature, COMP = 1 would be something like blood pressure. These are different biomarkers monitored per patients and the rationale behind each is so that clinicians can compare how they evolve over time, hence the need for unique scales for each COMP case.

Comment: You can't. You can only have two. This is a conscious design choice, since it is usually a bad idea to have even two different y axes. In your example, it doesn't seem to make much sense to have two axes, since the numbers are the same on both. Your data series are already labelled clearly and fit nicely on the plot. Why would you need a separate axis for each one? Just label the y axis as 'value' and the plot is perfectly understandable.

Comment: I did this dataset without actual real values to depict the challenge that I'm having when plotting multiple axis, but in actuality the scales are not equivalent. COMP is a code for a specific case, not multiple measurements (that's also why the times don't match), because I'm comparing multiple biomarkers to visualize their interplay vs. time (their scales are unique hence the need for more scales). Having multiple scales is actually needed; I forgot to add this piece of information, thanks to point that out.

Comment: In that case, you should use facets. Having 4 y axis scales is considered extremely poor practice from a data visualization point of view. It would be very difficult for anyone to read, and ugly compared to a simple faceted plot. There is a good reason for ggplot to make this difficult to do. It's not impossible, but it's far, far harder than using facets and would require some grob-hacking to do it.

Comment: See also this case against dual (!) axis alone: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/ - as I believe that hardly anyone would ever honestly have considered the idea of having 4 y axis, I don't believe you will find a similar post for that case

Comment: @AllanCameron although I find that idea absurd, I disagree with your comment that *you can't*. It also wouldn't require grob messing. Just a few fake axis with geom_segment or geom_vline and geom_text should suffice.

Comment: @tjebo of course. You can draw just about anything with ggplot. I guess my point is that you can't draw additional axes as actual axis objects using ggplot without grob hacking. "Faking" them with segments and text is also a valid approach, but my guess is that it would require even more code to calculate all the positions and add all the layers. Unusually, I'm not even tempted to try either approach here. It reminds me of Hebb's Law - 'if something's not worth doing, it's not worth doing well!'